# If C intertwines two positive operators, does C intertwines their square root?

Tags: normal-operator

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive invertible $n\times n$ matrices and $C$ be any $n\times n$   matrix such that $ A^2C= CB^2 $. Does this implies $AC=CB$ ?

I know the answer in a particular case when $A=B$ (using spectral theorem). But I have absolutely no idea for the general case. Please help me. Thanks in advance.